# Function Types as Parameter Types, how change UI element value in this function?

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, asynchronous

I'm get data from json async and want change UILabel text, but text no canhge. 
I think this doesn't work because function **changeLabel(...)** run **inside** func **getJsonArray(...)**, but why and how do this correct

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //load data from website, and run function changeLabel for change text on UI
    getJsonArray("www.domen.com/app.php?action=get_data", doItFunc: changeLabel)
}
```

function to change UILabel text

```
func changeLabel(jsonArray: NSArray){
    //self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = "workplease"
    self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = jsonArray[0]["newText"] as! String

    println(self.detailDescriptionLabel.text)
    //print in console new Data, but UILabel text in simulator(and phone) not change

}
```

Function to get data from net and run user function async

```
func getJsonArray(uri: String, doItFunc: (NSArray)->Void){

    if let url = NSURL(string: uri) {
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                println("error: \(error.localizedDescription): \(error.userInfo)")
            }else if data != nil {
                if let sJson = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                    let results: NSArray = sJson[jsonKey] as! NSArray
```

if data is get, run user function doItFunc(results)

```
                    doItFunc(results)

                }else{
                    if let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                        println("Received data:\n\(str)")
                    }else {
                        println("unable to convert data to text")
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
    else {
        println("Unable to create NSURL")
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data task callback where you parse the JSON is on a background thread. You can't update UI on a background thread. Dispatch to the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    doItFunc(results)
}
```